# Undefined variable: working with query

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, filter

I have gotten the following error:
 Undefined variable: get_crs_mysqli for the following line:

```
$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : '';
```

Essentially how it works is as follow:

What essentially happen is that a user search for a course, and then when they apply the optional search filter, it gets revised as to reflect the filter. For instance, they search all html, and it loads all html, and if they select duration 1 than it should only show html courses with 1 duration.

In particular, those filters are optional. when the page loads it reads the search query the user has entered and hence the result populated is based on its search. then when the user select a checkbox like category1 or category2 it goes into specifics. example. courses for html are populated, then user checks duration1 so all courses for html with only duration1 is shown if user checks duration1 and 2 then both html courses with duration1 and 2 is shown , and hence number of results shrink. at the start it doesnt take into account the filters, and hence results is larger.

Below is a picture that helps you visualize it:

[image]

With the help of this community, I arrive at this code:

```
$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : '';
$durationArr = array();
if (!empty($duration1)) $durationArr[] = $duration1;
if (!empty($duration2)) $durationArr[] = $duration2;
if (!empty($duration3)) $durationArr[] = $duration3;
if (count($durationArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_duration IN ('".implode("','", $durationArr)."') ";
 }

$guaranteeArr = array();
if (!empty($guarantee1)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee1;
if (!empty($guarantee2)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee2;
if (count($guaranteeArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_guarantee IN ('".implode("','", $guaranteeArr)."') ";
 }

$fieldsArr = array();
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_city']  = $city;
$fieldsArr['course_subc1']  = $category1;
$fieldsArr['course_subc2']  = $category2;
$fieldsArr['course_subc3']  = $category3;
$fieldsArr['course_subc4']  = $category4;
$fieldsArr['course_subc5']  = $category5;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery']  = $delivery1;
foreach ($fieldsArr as $key=>$val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  $key = $val ";
    }
}

$get_crs_mysqli .= "
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC 
    LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";

$get_crs=mysqli_query($con, $get_crs_mysqli);
```

if you require any question, let me know

Update:

Full Code;

```
<?php
session_start();

include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;
$duration1 = isset($_POST['duration1']) ? $_POST['duration1']: null; 
$duration2 = isset($_POST['duration2']) ? $_POST['duration2']: null; 
$duration3 = isset($_POST['duration3']) ? $_POST['duration3']: null; 
$duration4 = isset($_POST['duration4']) ? $_POST['duration4']: null; 
$duration5 = isset($_POST['duration5']) ? $_POST['duration5']: null; 
$delivery1 = isset($_POST['delivery1']) ? $_POST['delivery1']: null; 
$delivery2 = isset($_POST['delivery2']) ? $_POST['delivery2']: null; 
$category1 = isset($_POST['category1']) ? $_POST['category1']: null; 
$category2 = isset($_POST['category2']) ? $_POST['category2']: null; 
$category3 = isset($_POST['category3']) ? $_POST['category3']: null;
    $category4 = isset($_POST['category4']) ? $_POST['category4']: null; 
$category5 = isset($_POST['category5']) ? $_POST['category5']: null; 
$category6 = isset($_POST['category6']) ? $_POST['category6']: null;
$category7 = isset($_POST['category7']) ? $_POST['category7']: null; 
$category8 = isset($_POST['category8']) ? $_POST['category8']: null; 
$category9 = isset($_POST['category9']) ? $_POST['category9']: null;

$provider1 = isset($_POST['provider1']) ? $_POST['provider1']: null; 
$provider2 = isset($_POST['provider2']) ? $_POST['provider2']: null;
$provider3 = isset($_POST['provider3']) ? $_POST['provider3']: null; 
$provider4 = isset($_POST['provider4']) ? $_POST['provider4']: null; 
$provider5 = isset($_POST['provider5']) ? $_POST['provider5']: null;


$guarantee1 = isset($_POST['guarantee1']) ? $_POST['guarantee1']: null; 
$guarantee2 = isset($_POST['guarantee2']) ? $_POST['guarantee2']: null;

$city = isset($_POST['city1']) ? $_POST['city1']: null; 


//sanitize post value
if(isset($_POST["page"])){
  $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
  if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
}else{
  $page_number = 1;
}

$item_per_page = 10;
//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
global $con;
$p1 = 0;
$p2 = 4000;
  $get_crs_mysqli_count = " SELECT * 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE course_date1 >= CURRENT_DATE() 
       AND ( 
          (course_title like '%" . $_SESSION['userSearch'] . "%') 
          AND (
             (course_duration IN ('" . $duration1 . "','" . $duration2 . "','" . $duration3 . "','" . $duration4 . "','" . $duration5 . "') ) 
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "' ) 
          OR (course_guarantee IN ('" . $guarantee1 . "','" . $guarantee2 . "' ) )
          OR (course_city = '" . $city . "')
          OR (course_subc1 = '" . $category1 . "')
          OR (course_subc2 = '" . $category2 . "')
          OR (course_subc3 = '" . $category3 . "')
          OR (course_subc4 = '" . $category4 . "')
          OR (course_subc5 = '" . $category5 . "')
          OR (course_delivery2 = '" . $delivery2 . "')
          OR (course_delivery = '" . $delivery1 . "' )
          )
          OR (course_duration = '" . $duration1 . "')
        ) 
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC ";

$get_crs_mysqli .= (!empty($_SESSION['userSearch']))?(" AND course_title like '%".$_SESSION['userSearch']."%' ") : '';

$durationArr = array();
if (!empty($duration1)) $durationArr[] = $duration1;
if (!empty($duration2)) $durationArr[] = $duration2;
if (!empty($duration3)) $durationArr[] = $duration3;
if (count($durationArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_duration IN ('".implode("','", $durationArr)."') ";
 }

$guaranteeArr = array();
if (!empty($guarantee1)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee1;
if (!empty($guarantee2)) $guaranteeArr[] = $guarantee2;
if (count($guaranteeArr)>0) {
    $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  (course_guarantee IN ('".implode("','", $guaranteeArr)."') ";
 }

$fieldsArr = array();
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_city']  = $city;
$fieldsArr['course_subc1']  = $category1;
$fieldsArr['course_subc2']  = $category2;
$fieldsArr['course_subc3']  = $category3;
$fieldsArr['course_subc4']  = $category4;
$fieldsArr['course_subc5']  = $category5;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery2']  = $delivery2;
$fieldsArr['course_delivery']  = $delivery1;
foreach ($fieldsArr as $key=>$val) {
    if (!empty($val)) {
        $get_crs_mysqli .= " AND  $key = $val ";
    }
}

$get_crs_mysqli .= "
    ORDER BY course_date1 ASC 
    LIMIT  $position, $item_per_page";

$get_crs=mysqli_query($con, $get_crs_mysqli);
$get_crs_count=mysqli_query($con, $get_crs_mysqli_count);

// Get total of Num rows from the database query
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;


$count_cats = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs);
  if ($count_cats==0){

    echo "<h2 style='padding:20px;'>No course(s) were found.</h2>";

  }

  //output results from database
echo '<ul class="page_result">';

while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($get_crs)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  



      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}




echo '</ul>';





?>
```

Comment: Please show the code that comes before this. That error just means that by the time you're trying to append stuff to the string with `.=`, you haven't instantiated it with just `=` yet.

Comment: hi thank you for your response. I have posted under my initial post an update with the complete code for the page

Comment: Where is the beginning of your query? That's what is missing. I would expect to see something like `$get_crs_mysqli = 'SELECT * FROM ...'` before you start adding `AND` clauses.

Comment: so would this work ?  $get_crs_mysqli = " SELECT * 
    FROM courses 
    WHERE";

Comment: i now get the following error when i try to use that line Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: any help would be appreciated